# Is it ok to update an answer by replacing the original code with code from another answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I witnessed today some behaviour that I find questionable from a fellow answerer. I'm wondering if it's an acceptable behaviour by the standards of the community. Here's what happened:

Some user answered to a question with some correct but perfectible code. Three months later, I added a better answer. Then the first answerer edited his answer to replace his own code with the better code I provided in my answer, save for some formatting and variable names. My answer being months fresher than his, it has less upvotes and thus appears below. It now looks like I was the one that ripped the answer from the other. No attribution is given in the answer.

None of the answers is an original, clever trick to do some hard thing but simple documentation, 3-lines code sample and advice on best practices.

Comment: It happens; to be true the other answer has never been better than mine after this (but has always has more votes). The hoped for end goal is that the world is a better place and that the best answer is out in the wild. If you're feeling really bitter (understandable) then Downvote the other answer; otherwise, get on with life and being the best you can be. You'll get rep quicker doing that than stewing over one answer...

Comment: Nobody can steal your original work and claim it as their own, attribution is required.  You make it a bit murky by hinting that it wasn't original and not copied verbatim.  Flag a moderator and ask him to look at it.

Comment: If you are going to give someone else's answer to a question, mark it as *community wiki*. That basically means you didn't come up with the answer yourself.

Comment: Thank you @worldofjr, this is a nice idea. It plays at everyone's benefit. I will ask him that.